# Accessing collection in controller in mongodb, express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

How can I access the collection in the controller in mongodb, express? I found in mongodb documentation `db.getCollection("countries");` How can I import name da tabase: `db` into a controller?

**server**

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();

// Connect to our Database and handle an bad connections
mongoose
    .connect(process.env.DATABASE, { 
        useNewUrlParser: true, 
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useUnifiedTopology: true, 
        useCreateIndex: true
    })
    .then(() => console.log("DB server connect"))
    .catch(error => console.log("DB error", error))

const countriesRoutes = require('./routes/countries');

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//middleware
app.use('/api', countriesRoutes);

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`connect on the port ${port} - ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`);
});
```

**controllers/countries**

```
module.exports.read = (req, res) => {

    const countries = db.getCollection("countries");
    console.log(countries)

    if(err || !countries) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: "Countries not found"
        })
    }

    res.json(countries);
};
```

**routes/countries**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const {read} = require('../controllers/countries');

router.get('/countries', read);

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `createConnection`

```
module.exports.db = mongoose
    .createConnection(process.env.DATABASE, { 
        useNewUrlParser: true, 
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useUnifiedTopology: true, 
        useCreateIndex: true
    })
```

And import it in your controller

I would also create a seperate file called `connection.js` and write it in there so you dont bloat your main file

Comment: all the time I have `db.getCollection` is not a function

Comment: It works. But in controller I had to use:     `db.db.collection('countries').findOne({}, function (findErr, countries) {
        if (findErr) throw findErr;
        console.log(countries);

        res.json(countries);
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Create a file db.js and create [mongoose schema model](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition) for Countries

```
const config = require('../../config/config.json');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const connectionOptions = { useCreateIndex: true, useNewUrlParser: true, 
                            useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false };
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || config.connectionString, connectionOptions);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

module.exports = {
    Countries: require('./models/countries.model'),
}
```

Now in your controller import the db file and simply

```
const db = require('./db');
const Countries = db.Countries;
const response = await Countries.find({});
```

Comment: Do I have to create model "country" by mongoose schema model? I inserted handle countries to database by mongoDb compass (website). I need only collection countries t fetch and display in select dropdown.

Comment: I would recommend you to create a simple schema for this.